# <In App Purchase> how to generate a SKProduct directly

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

recently I working on `IAP`.
As you know, when you want to send a payment request, you should call

```
+ (id)paymentWithProduct:(SKProduct *)product
```

but I found only way to get product is using `SKProductsRequest`, is there any way to generate `SKProduct` directly?
just like the deprecated one,

```
+ (id)paymentWithProductIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

The fact is I want a new `SKProduct` object directly using product id.

BR, Roger

Comment: If this would be possible, you would not need to insert new products to `ITunesConnect`, and Apple could not track the sold products. Maybe  you can mark the answer as correct, as there is no way to do it in a different way

Answer (score 18):

I use this to buy a product without fetching all the products from iTunes:

```
  - (void)buyProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier 
{
    SKMutablePayment *payment = [[SKMutablePayment alloc] init] ;
    payment.productIdentifier = productIdentifier;
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you were wanting to create a `SKProduct` for unit testing purposes, you can extend the class and set the identifiers:

```
extension SKProduct {
    convenience init(identifier: String, price: String, priceLocale: Locale) {
        self.init()
        self.setValue(identifier, forKey: "productIdentifier")
        self.setValue(NSDecimalNumber(string: price), forKey: "price")
        self.setValue(priceLocale, forKey: "priceLocale")
    }
}
```

Comment: A hacky way that does not comply with Apple's recommendation.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such mechanism.  You have to get your In-App purchases approved by Apple and use the SKProductsRequest API to retrieve the pricing information.

Answer (score 0):

You could create `SKMutablePayment` instead of `SKPayment`:

```swift
let payment = SKMutablePayment()
payment.productIdentifier = <#ProductIdentifier#>
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
```